# Unsupported depth of input image: > 'VDepth::contains(depth)' > where > 'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use hand tracking but still giving me errors I tried using `astype -> float32` but still gave me an error regarding the bool value doest have `astype`

this is the line of code that gives me the first error
imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)

```
def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectCon=0.5, trCon=0.5):

    self.mode = mode

    self.maxHands = maxHands

    self.detectCon = detectCon

    self.trCon = trCon

    self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands

    self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectCon, self.trCon)

    self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

def findHands(self, img, draw = True):

    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)

    results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:

        for handL in results.multi_hand_landmarks:

            if draw:

                self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handL, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

    return img


def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    detector = handDetector
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img, True)
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime
        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (60, 50, 255), 3)
        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        Q = cv2.waitKey(33)
        if(Q)==27:
           break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please share more details?

Comment: the first two functions are in a class

Comment: please present a [mre]. your code is not suitable to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but have you tried this :

```
img_float32 = np.float32(img)
imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img_float32, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
```

Comment: another error after using the answer :   cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Comment: i dont need to convert it if i remove the class itd work but adding a class seems to be the problem here

Comment: I made a mistake: the argument of cvtColor was supposed to be img_float32 and not img_float.
Using a class should not change anything. If you think it'll work, be careful to test cautiously.

Comment: i just solved it and dont worry i noticed the little mistake its ok it worked i wrote the 32 but gave me another error and after alot of changes i discovered the problem it was the hands properties i needed to remove some of them thanks foor the helppp appreciate it

Comment: Glad you solved it. Do not hesitate to share your solution to others who can have the same problem.